# Words Finding in Website from csv list, issue is : below code is fetching only last record

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter

#reading file which is contain sample records

```
merifile = pd.read_csv("samplefcarecord.csv")
```

#creating empty list to store words

```
wordsinwebsite = []
link = row.url
company = row.Company
words = ['Life Insurance', 'General Insurance', 'Motor Fleet','Fleet 
Insurance', 'Motor Home Insurance', 'Insurance', 'Mortgages', 'Property 
Insurance', 'Fire Insurance', 'Liability Insurance', 'Personal Insurance', 
'Motor Fleet Insurance', 'Car Insurance', 'Travel Insurance', 'Home 
Insurance', 'Pet Insurance', 'Health Insurance', 'Vehicle Insurance', 
'Wealth Insurance', 'Income Protection Insurance', 'Auto Insurance', 
'Building Insurance', 'Buildings Insurance', 'Disability Insurance', 'Common 
Insurance', 'Guarantee Insurance', 'Social Insurance', 'Two-Wheeler 
Insurance', 'Bike Insurance', 'Truck Insurance', 'Four Wheeler Insurance', 
'Four-Wheeler Insurance', '4-wheeler insurance', '2-wheeler insurance', 
'Business Insurance', 'Pawnbroking' , 'Travel Money', 'Used Cars', 'New 
Cars']
site = urllib.request.urlopen(link).read().decode("utf-8")
```

#for loop to fetch each url from list, but its fetching only last record url

```
for word in words:
        if word in site:
            anchorandurldata = { 'Company' : company , 'url': link, 'word': 
       wordsinwebsite}
            wordsinwebsite.append(word)
        else:
            pass
```

Comment: https://1drv.ms/x/s!AiXreQ14KN7CgQe-GCu0vop-97Kb Here is sheet which is containing the sample records

Comment: This is very unclear. Is this a function? is it meant to return something? There's nothing being printed or returned, so where are you expecting the values to be?

Comment: Your list variable is enterwordsinwebsite = [] but you are appending to wordsinwebsite. Is this what you want ? If yes, include all of your core logic. Otherwise correct the variable.

Comment: What i am trying to do is, i am fetching every url which is in csv sheet, and checking whether the words in the list created above is in that website or not, if not it is displaying nothing, if it is present then it is displaying in the next column

Comment: I am getting the result correctly, but only for the last record not for all

Comment: @Nair that was incorrectly typed, correct list is wordsinwebsite

Comment: @OferSadan there are some words in a list named : 'words'. I am checking url from csv sheet and checking if any of these words are in that website or not, if yes then storing the value in wordsinwebsite, otherwise not.